# About share app on google play via Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I have 1 app but i divide it to 2 special app: 1 for smartphone and 1 for tablet with 2 different package name (A for smart and B for Tab). But i have problem: when i share my app (A) via Facebook sdk from smartphone so other smartphone can go & download it from store but other tablet can't not do that because store prevent this app on Tab (A) and vice versa with share app B on Tab. So can i fix it without combine A and B to 1 package.

Thanks all;

Comment: Do you use the same Facebook Key for 2 version (Phone & tablet)?

Comment: @Liem Vo: No i use 2 different FB key